# Matplotlib Italic in portion of axes labels - applied to default font but not specified font

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts, label, italic

I want all text in my plots to be Times New Roman, so I did the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams["font.family"] = "Times New Roman" # change default font
```

and I only want the '(x)' and '(z)' portions of my labels to be italics, so I did:

```
plt.xlabel('Underutilization $\it{(x)}$', labelpad=15)
plt.ylabel('Productivity $\it{(z)}$', labelpad=15)
```

However, what I end up with upon plotting is 'Underutilization' in Times New Roman, but '(x)' in an italicized sans serif (the default of Python). Same with the ylabel.

How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text inside the `$` signs is dictated by matplotlib’s [mathtext](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html) (unless you are using LaTex), and is controlled by the `rcParam` `mathtext.fontset` which is outlined in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html) by

> mathtext.fontset: ‘dejavusans’ (default)
>      ‘dejavuserif’, ‘cm’ (Computer Modern), ‘stix’,
>      ‘stixsans’ or ‘custom’

Using [LaTex for the text rendering](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/usetex.html) offers more flexibility in font choice, and I believe would support Times New Roman. If you use LaTex then it should adjust the math font when you adjust `font.family`.